# Uploading artifacts is disabled

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Does anyone know how to resolve "**Missing gitlab-runner. Uploading artifacts is disabled.**"

I have two ssh runner on my server. One for local ssh runner and another one is remote server ssh runner. The local ssh runner working perfectly. But when I call the remote shh runner it's building successfully but it shows "Missing gitlab-runner. Uploading artifacts is disabled." so that I'm not able to call the artifact in the next stage.

The gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - build script
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
  only:
    - master
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - deploy script
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem? I have a same and my executor is 'shell'.

Comment: I have found it's a permission problem, only `root` can use `gitlab-runner` command by default, so we should add `gitlab-runner` user authority

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `gitlab-runner` also on the ssh target host. Gitlab somehow needs this to upload artifacts.  This is also documented now: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/ssh.html:

> If you want to upload job artifacts, install `gitlab-runner` on the host you are connecting to via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `gitlab-runner` in the path `~/bin` and add `~/bin` to your variable PATH.